# Using sizeof() with struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, sizeof

Consider

```
struct abc
{
int a;
int b;
};
```

What is the difference between `sizeof(struct abc)` and `sizeof(struct abc*)` ?

Comment: Check the syntax; There are two syntactic constructions for sizeof: `sizeof expr` and `sizeof(type)` (where `expr` is any expression, and type is a typename) (in your case: both cases are of the form `sizeof(type)`, but with different types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `sizeof` will return the size of the struct, the second returns the sizeof a pointer on your computer (probably 64-bits).
It's harder to guess what the first `sizeof` will return, because struct's can have padding and/or alignment constraints that varies from compiler to compiler or from ABI to ABI.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, if you print the result of the two sizeof() operations, they will both probably be the same (it depends on your system), but that's a coincidence. You can more clearly see the difference if you change the size of the struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct abc
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("sizeof(struct abc): %ld\n", sizeof(struct abc));
    printf("sizeof(struct abc *): %ld\n", sizeof(struct abc *));

    return 0;
}
```

This will print (again, depending on your system, but this is what you'll get on 64-bit unix):

```
sizeof(struct abc): 12
sizeof(struct abc *): 8
```

And from that you can guess the difference: the first one is showing you the size of the structure, and the second is showing you the size of a pointer.